# Package Updater could not get list of distribution upgrade

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

Opening Package Updater saying a message `All packages are up to date`.

Behind that a error message saying

**`Could not get list of distribution upgrades`**

```
Failed to process request
```

**in more details** I get:

```
Spawn of helper '/usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py' failed: failed to spawn /usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py: Failed to execute child process “/usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py” (No such file or directory)
```

Tried the following commands but all are doing fine accept openning the package updater.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

Answer (score 1):

A bug has been already reported in the official [site](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-packagekit/+bug/1709699)

It has been officially confirmed, so you can follow the link and wait there for there solutions.