# Could not get list of distribution upgrades

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

When I open package updater I get the error message:

```
Spawn of helper '/usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py' failed: failed to spawn /usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py: Failed to execute child process “/usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py” (No such file or directory)
```

I see A similar question where one answer indicates a solution on an official site. Where is the solution? I cant make any sense out of the site at all. Is there even a solution yet or are they still working on that bug?

Comment: Please use formatting, or at least line-breaks (if it had line breaks I'd have cleaned it up myself for you).  You saw a similar question?  If you've had provided a link I'd have looked and may have been able to understand what you mean by official site.  I don't know your release, and suspect you've got a corrupted $PATH or have made changes to the default python causing your issues - but correct formatting of your question, your Ubuntu release & link would have made it less blind-guess.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075732/package-updater-could-not-get-list-of-distribution-upgrade and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149442/get-distro-upgrade-py-failed-to-execute-process

Comment: I do not know how to provide a link. The instructions at bottom are not clear. do i use[ ] or ( )? The first link provided by DK Bose brougt me to the same ubuntu site it is bugs.launshpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-packagekit/bug/1709699 I have not found the solution and it is affecting 2 hard drives both ubuntu 18.04.2. I have not made changes to python in the spare hard drive possibly the other one, not sure though. What is a $PATH? Not sure if it is corrupted, but why would both hard drives have a corrupted $PATH? @guiverc

Comment: $PATH is an environment variable. The command `echo $PATH` will show the directories that are searched for commands to execute, so if altered (usually in error) some commands can seem to disappear (won't be found & errors appear). The command `echo $USER` will display your username etc, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables  That is a shell issue, the other I suspected was python change  (`python --version` should respond a valid 2.7 version, `python3 --version` a valid 3.x version for 18.04.  *Please add line-breaks to your error message.*

Comment: II have made no changes to $PATH and as I stated earlier I have made no changes to python either. Other than that what exactly do you mean? tThere are nmo instructions on how to provide a line break. And what is a line break?

Comment: I cant make any sense out of that help site you suggested.  Again I have made no changes to python in the new hard drive and I do not believe any were made to the old hard drive iether. LIne breaks what? @guiverc

Comment: I code-blocked your paste; there are no line-breaks (\n) in your paste which is what I had requested you to fix, as it is hard to read when not correctly formatted. The line breaks allow subsequent lines to be recognized as new lines instead of continuations of the prior lines. You still haven't provided the similar question, nor python answers requested (as I suspect it's changes there which is why I asked for --version details). The wiki page I thought was boring & technical but mostly clear; but without answers to prior requested details I cannot help.

Comment: What is a line Break? I asked before and did not get an answer. I have tried $PATH and it does not provide my username in the path directory.

Comment: Command $USER output is: command not found              I can't provide a link without clear instructions. @guiverc

Comment: the command `echo $USER` as I entered it (it was highlighted with different formatting to reflect the command, the command being `echo` with operand $USER.  I still haven't seen your output for `python --version; python3 --version`  which will confirm you did nothing, or my suspicion that you've made changes to your python or $PATH  Line breaks are the character that signifies the end of the line so the cursor moves to the start of the line below; be it LF, CR or CF+LF etc. Look at your error message - without line breaks it's one long line (if you look at edit history; I only code-tagged)